# An anchor at the bottom of the /reputation page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation-page

Would be nice with something like a `#bottom` anchor at the bottom of the http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation page.

(Scrolling to the bottom isn't much of a problem when I'm on a laptop, but it's really terrible when I'm on my iPad or on my cell phone.)

Comment: Agreed. The `End` key makes this pretty simple when a full keyboard is available, but no dice on mobile devices. Great idea, +1.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103418/can-the-most-important-information-of-reputation-audit-appear-first

Comment: That's a dup of this one?

Comment: The anchor is already there: http://stackoverflow.com/reputation#bottom