# Can the most important information of reputation audit appear first?

Tags: feature-request, reputation-audit

I regularly find myself having to scroll to the bottom of the reputation audit to find all the good stuff that appears last. On my computer this is a single key press, but on my mobile it takes 30 seconds of scrolling. Lord alone knows how long it would be for Jon Skeet!

Since the principles of good user experience suggest putting the most important information first, why not do the same here? I never look at my first 5 days of rep gathering. But I often look at the current day, the true rep, days with 200 rep (hunting legendary badge!), trigger recalc etc. Pretty please, can we have it up top?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Workaround until this gets implemented:*

Just bookmark the following URL: [`https://stackoverflow.com/reputation#bottom`](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation#bottom).

This works because the form at the bottom obviously has the id "bottom":

```
<form id="bottom" method="post" action="/reputation?recalc=true">
```

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion which I will use. The proposed change still makes a lot of sense though.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree with you.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there was a `#bottom` anchor. If so, how about just adding a link to that anchor at the `#top` of the page?

Comment: Hah. Excellent edit and suggestion @Cody.