# Reputation audit provides no way to readily obtain the most recent information

Tags: feature-request, reputation-audit

Way back when, I asked this question: [Can the most important information of reputation audit appear first?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103418/can-the-most-important-information-of-reputation-audit-appear-first)

I would like for the most recent information to appear first. But it appears at the end which can take a while to scroll to on a non-desktop device.

Not to worry, the answer I accepted suggested using https://stackoverflow.com/reputation#bottom as a workaround. Because the thoughtful designers spat this out in the HTML for https://stackoverflow.com/reputation:

```
<form id="bottom" method="post" action="/reputation?recalc=true">
```

Sadly that is no longer there. Having removed the recalculation button, you have also removed the shortcut to see the important information.

Please, please can you find a way to show the good stuff at the top, or provide a way for us to get to it easily.

Comment: Chrome F12 --> Console --> `document.body.scrollTop = document.body.scrollHeight;`

Comment: And looks like Chrome have this [even on mobile devices](http://www.engadget.com/2013/12/03/chrome-devtools-now-lets-you-see-how-websites-behave-on-mobile/). :)

Comment: The developers removed that button because [it screwed up debugging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212622/what-happened-to-my-reputation-dropped-about-1500-points?noredirect=1#comment684600_212622)

Comment: @Amicable The button removal was fine. The collateral damage is the problem.