# Please use anchors on the SE blog

Tags: feature-request, blog, anchor

On a number of occasions now I've found myself referring to blog posts containing site policy or usage guidelines, and wanting to refer to specific sections in them (e.g. point 2 in [these editing guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/)).

There have been a number of requests for anchors, which have generally been implemented:
[on the How to Ask help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89440/add-anchors-to-the-how-to-ask-and-how-to-answer-pages) (not implemented though the FAQ is different now),
[on user pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35490/add-anchors-to-the-user-pages) (superseded by the user page tabs),
[in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts) (very upvoted but not implemented),
[to the reputation page's bottom](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90562/an-anchor-at-the-bottom-of-the-reputation-page) (implemented)
[to specific revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112379/add-anchors-to-revisions) (implemented)
[on the legal pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115006/please-add-anchors-to-the-sections-on-the-legal-page) (implemented)
and
[in the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93648/add-discoverable-anchor-links-to-the-faq) (implemented and then superseded by the new FAQ design).

This one is slightly different but in the same spirit: **could blog writers include `names` in section headers to allow for linking to specific sections or bullet points where relevant?** Alternatively, could the blog software be expanded to insert automatic anchors into paragraphs, and maybe even auto linkers to headers and lists?

EDIT: [This](http://fortran90.org/src/best-practices.html#fortran-style-guide) is the kind of CSS I'm thinking about. So handy!

Answer (score 4):

Modifying the blog software isn't going to happen, but I can add anchors easily enough - I've done this before when I needed them on other blog posts, but... Uh, didn't exactly make them *discoverable*.

See what you think of [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/).

Comment: I like 'em. (They're slightly intrusive and it would be nice to have them appear on mouseover but that's definitely nitpicking.) I guess it's probably asking too much to get them back-ported except into a small selection (should we make a list?), but those would be nice on future blog posts.

Comment: Make a list, please

Comment: I'll have a look for likely ones and add a wiki answer with them later.